# Generic Repository for SQLite-Net in Xamarin Project

Tags: c#, xamarin, repository-pattern, sqlite-net

I am wondering if there is a way to write a generic repository for my Xamarin project versus writing a different Repository for each entity in my object. The Xamarin [Tasky Pro](https://github.com/xamarin/mobile-samples/blob/master/TaskyPro/Tasky.Core/DataAccessLayer/TaskRepository.cs) example have one Repository for the Task entity because that is the only entity it has.

In my own project I have more than one Entity, so my question is how can I make 
the following Customer Repository to become generic so that the ProductManager, EmployeeManager, etc can use it. If you know of an example or a blog post please point me to the right direction

```
namespace App.DataLayer
{
    public class CustomerRepository
    {
        private ProntoDatabase _db = null;
        protected static string DbLocation;
        protected static CustomerRepository Me;

        static CustomerRepository()
        {
            Me = new CustomerRepository();
        }

        protected CustomerRepository()
        {
            //set the db location;
            DbLocation = DatabaseFilePath;

            //instantiate the database
            _db = new ProntoDatabase(DbLocation);
        }


        public static string DatabaseFilePath
        {
            get
            {
                const string sqliteFilename = "CustomerDB.db3";
                var libraryPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                var path = Path.Combine(libraryPath, sqliteFilename);
                return path;
            }
        }


        // CRUD (Create, Read, Update and Delete) methods

        public static Customer GetCustomer(int id)
        {
            return Me._db.GetItem<Customer>(id);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Customer> GetCustomers()
        {
            return Me._db.GetItems<Customer>();
        }

        public static int SaveCustomer(Customer item)
        {
            return Me._db.SaveItem(item);
        }

        public static int DeleteCustomer(int id)
        {
            return Me._db.DeleteItem<Customer>(id);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You now have to pass in an implementation of ISQlitePlatform in the SQLiteConnectionWithLock and SQLiteConnection constructors. The correct platform implementation is automatically added to the project.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

This is an old question but here is my implementation.

I´m using async connections as they provide better performance in mobile projects. The nuggets I installed are `Sqlite.Net-PCL`/`SQLite.Net.Async-PCL` on the Core project and the corresponding nuget on the Android project.

My Repository looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Core.Models;
using SQLite.Net;
using System.Linq;
using SQLite.Net.Async;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Core.Managers
{
    public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        Task<List<T>> Get();
        Task<T> Get(int id);
        Task<List<T>> Get<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> orderBy = null);
        Task<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        AsyncTableQuery<T> AsQueryable();
        Task<int> Insert(T entity);
        Task<int> Update(T entity);
        Task<int> Delete(T entity);
    }

    public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()
    {
        private SQLiteAsyncConnection db;

        public Repository(SQLiteAsyncConnection db)
        {
            this.db = db;
        }

        public AsyncTableQuery<T> AsQueryable() => 
            db.Table<T>();

        public async Task<List<T>> Get() => 
            await db.Table<T>().ToListAsync();

        public async Task<List<T>> Get<TValue>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate = null, Expression<Func<T, TValue>> orderBy = null)
        {
            var query = db.Table<T>();

            if (predicate != null)
                query = query.Where(predicate);

            if (orderBy != null)
                query = query.OrderBy<TValue>(orderBy);

            return await query.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<T> Get(int id) => 
             await db.FindAsync<T>(id);

        public async Task<T> Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate) =>
            await db.FindAsync<T>(predicate);

        public async Task<int> Insert(T entity) => 
             await db.InsertAsync(entity);

        public async Task<int> Update(T entity) =>
             await db.UpdateAsync(entity);

        public async Task<int> Delete(T entity) =>
             await db.DeleteAsync(entity);
    }
}
```

Some examples on how to use it:

```
var connection = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(() => sqlite.GetConnectionWithLock());
await connection.CreateTablesAsync<Ingredient, Stock>();

IRepository<Stock> stockRepo = new Repository<Stock>(connection);
IRepository<Ingredient> ingredientRepo = new Repository<Ingredient>(connection);

var stock1 = new Stock { 
    IngredientId = 1,
    DaysToExpire = 3,
    EntryDate = DateTime.Now,
    Location = StockLocations.Fridge,
    MeasureUnit = MeasureUnits.Liter,
    Price = 5.50m,
    ProductName = "Leche Auchan",
    Quantity = 3,
    Picture = "test.jpg",
    Family = IngredientFamilies.Dairy
};

var stockId = await stockRepo.Insert(stock1);

var all = await stockRepo.Get();
var single = await stockRepo.Get(72);
var search = await stockRepo.Get(x => x.ProductName.StartsWith("something"));
var orderedSearch = await stockRepo.Get(predicate: x => x.DaysToExpire < 4, orderBy: x => x.EntryDate);
```

If the Repository does not meet your query needs, you can use AsQueryable():

```
public async Task<List<Stock>> Search(string searchQuery, StockLocations location, IngredientFamilies family)
{
    var query = stockRepo.AsQueryable();

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchQuery))
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.ProductName.Contains(searchQuery) || x.Barcode.StartsWith(searchQuery));
    }
    if (location != StockLocations.All)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Location == location);
    }
    if (family != IngredientFamilies.All)
    {
        query = query.Where(x => x.Family == family);
    }

    return await query.OrderBy(x => x.ExpirationDays).ToListAsync();
}
```

Comment: Wow, great. That is exactly what I am looking for. I will put it to use and see if I can use it to replace my 7 different repositories

Comment: The owner has unlisted `Sqlite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid` package. This could mean that the package is deprecated or shouldn't be used anymore. [LINK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLite.Net.Platform.XamarinAndroid/)

Comment: How did this work without the "public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()"

Comment: @PEO Could you find a solution for it? My compiler also complains abuout "public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : new()". The error message is :"The type 'T' must be a reference type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'IRepository<T>'"

Comment: Add "class" next to the interface where . simply your class should be "public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, new()"

Comment: For anyone thinking of using async repositories, I would recommend to think twice. Here are the reasons why: http://xleon.net/xamarin/dotnet/sqlite-net/async/2017/02/15/sqlite-net-async-vs-sync/

Comment: It's working fine, but I'm not getting the actual sqlite db file on my device

Comment: Awesome, that’s my problem for the day sorted out. Your solution is giving me a headache but it works!

Answer (score 3):

My implementation with the help of unity IOC is given below, My project includes the PCL, Xamarin Android & Xamarin iOS projects

Define a base model with primary key

```
public class BaseModel
{
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Define a generic base repository as shown below

```
public interface IBaseRepository<T> : IDisposable
    where T :BaseModel, new()
    {
        List<T> GetItems();

        T GetItem(int id);

        int GetItemsCount();

        int SaveItem(T item);

        int SaveAllItem(IEnumerable<T> items);
    }


public class BaseRepository<T> : BaseRepository<T> where T : BaseModel, new()
    {
        private static readonly object locker = new object();
        protected SQLiteConnection DatabaseConnection;
        public BaseRepository(string dbPath)
        {
            DatabaseConnection = new SQLiteConnection(dbPath);
            DatabaseConnection.CreateTable<T>();
        }

        public List<T> GetItems()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return DatabaseConnection.Table<T>().ToList();
            }
        }

        public int GetItemsCount()
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return DatabaseConnection.Table<T>().Count();
            }
        }

        public T GetItem(int id)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                return DatabaseConnection.Table<T>().Where(i => i.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            }
        }

        public int SaveItem(T item)
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                if (item.Id != 0)
                {
                    return DatabaseConnection.Update(item);
                }
                else
                {
                    return DatabaseConnection.Insert(item);
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Define two sample classes which are inherited from the BaseModel

```
public class Entity1 : BaseModel
    {
        public int ItemName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }


public class Entity2 : BaseModel
{
    public int Description
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}


public static UnityContainer Container { get; private set; }

    public static void InitializeUnityContainer()
    {
        if (Container == null)
            Container = new UnityContainer();
    }
```

Register

```
Container.RegisterInstance<IBaseRepository<Entity1>>(new BaseRepository<Entity1>(DatabasePath));
    Container.RegisterInstance<IBaseRepository<Entity2>>(new BaseRepository<Entity2>(DatabasePath));
```

resolve like this

```
using (var repo1 = App.Container.Resolve<IBaseRepository<Entity2>>())
{

}
```

Comment: where UnityContainer is defined?