# Xamarin SQLite.NET Generic TableQuery

Tags: android, xamarin, sqlite.net

I use the component "SQLite.NET" in my Xamarin-project.
I have several "models/classes" like "Document","Project".
Each model has its own Table in SQLite.

To get the data from a table, i'm using the following technique:

```
List<Document> documents = new SQLiteConnection("..DB-path..").Table<Document>.ToList();
```

It works fine, but for each table I have to do the same code and only changing the Model-type in the code above.

Now I would like to write a generic method where I can do:

```
List<T> data = new SQLiteConnection("..DB-path..").Table<T>.ToList();
```

But unfortunately, I get the following error:

> 'T' must be a non-abstract type with a public parameterless constructor in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'SQLiteConnection.Table()'

Does anyone know a way to create a generic method for the problem above?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you include the entire method that contains your line of code using generic types? How are you declaring `T`? As a side note, you don't need to create a new `SQLiteConnection` every time you access the database, in fact it is considered better practice to use a singleton connection.

Comment: If you also want generic queries, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29050400/generic-repository-for-sqlite-net-in-xamarin-project/29856945#29856945

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add constraint to you function.

```
public List<T> GetData<T> () where T: new()
{
    using(var connection = new SQLiteConnection("..DB-path..")){
       return connection.Table<T>.ToList();
    }
}
```

Do not forget to dispose your DB connection!

Comment: Disposing the connection can sometimes throw if other parallel queries occur at the same time (if you use async queries). I would use just one connection that would keep open in whole app live cycle instead

Comment: @xleon Thats true, and i agree with you, that it is better to use one connection. But  Benjamin's current implementation does not utilize this approach. So in case, when you do not reuse connection, you should dispose it ASAP and utilize "try-with-resources".